# stonefield query web application cannot publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

i have problem publishing my web application on IIS. i'm using stonefield query tools which using `SQProxyWrapper` component.

When i publish the page on IIS i got this error:

> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F83BAE78-C971-4083-B191-64AE6790104E} failed due to the following error: 80070005.
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F83BAE78-C971-4083-B191-64AE6790104E} failed due to the following error: 80070005.]
>      SQProxyWrapper.SQProxy..ctor() +26

I believe that the component 'SQProxyWrapper' is blocked. The stonefield query use 2 dll SQProxyWrapper.dll and SFQWrapper.dll . is there anything that i need to do to this 2 dll before publishing the web application to IIS?

I tried to put the whole files and folders security to full access to everyone but no luck I still got the same error.

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491123/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-compone

Comment: i try to find the Sqproxy, sfqwrapper, sqproxywrapper or anything related to the stonefield component in the DCOM in Component services but the component is not there...

Comment: Maybe you need to register it. Why you do not ask the company of it ?

Comment: i tried register the component with regsvr32 "c:\sqproxywrapper.dll" command but it return an error : sqproxywrapper.dll was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found ..

Comment: i hope the company found the solution and reply the answer , i still looking all over the web , search on google , yahoo ,  etc and try lots of thing but i still got the same error..

Comment: Doug Hennig of Stonefield recommends filing a support ticket at http://www.stonefieldsoftware.com/helpdesk/index.php?a=add