# .NET dll called from classic ASP, IIS7.5

Tags: asp-classic, interop, iis-7.5

I have a .NET, COM visible DLL written in C# that I am calling from classic ASP page.

It all works fine on the 32-bit Win Server 2003 and IIS 6, but I cannot get it to go on my 64-bit development machine (Win7, IIS 7.5).

I get the follwing error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'
>
> ActiveX component can't create object

It fails on the line

> set objMyDll = Server.CreateObject("MyDLL.ProgId")

I registered my DLL using `regasm /codebase` and it all looks good in the registry.

I also tried `regasm /tlb` and putting the DLL into GAC to no avail.

I have enabled 32 bit applications in my IIS.

I tried it in both classic and integrated mode in the app pool.

My DLL does not reference any other DLLs.

Comment: Do you know if you used the 32-bit or 64-bit regasm? See this previous SO post for correct locations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372140/c-sharp-com-dll-do-i-use-regasm-or-regsvr32

Comment: Thanks AardVark71. This fixed it. I used only the 32 bit regasm. Once I registered the DLL with the 64 bit regasm, it all worked. Unfortunately, I got too excited and clicked the upvote twice, and now I cannot give you the recognition this deserves.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you some errors in Event log? I think, you need grant execute and launch permission for specified ProgID in COM+ settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue. I just recentrly wrote **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251240/installed-word-on-the-server-but-cannot-find-it-to-set-permissions-in-component/15490603#15490603)** - check it out.