# Working with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and COM exception Access is denied

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to read text from MS-word (doc/docx) file using c#. When I am running my apps under admin account then no problem is occurring but when I am running under a user which has not admin privilege then this below error occur. I am running my apps on windows 2008 64 bit.

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory
>   for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed
>   due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

So please guide me what kind of permission I need to give to the user as a result com exception should not occur when I will read a doc/docx file programmatically by c#. Please discuss in details what are the steps I need to follow. Thanks.

Comment: I believe one simple solution will be run both as administrator or run both as normal privilege level

Comment: when run as admin then no prob occur but when run as normal user then problem occur. my win form exe is invoke by win schedular.

Comment: Have you considered running your application permanently in admin mode?

Comment: my prob solved just following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491123/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-word-in/3491486#3491486