# MSProject COM Interop unstable behavior

Tags: c#, com-interop, ms-project

We are extensively using COM Interop with MSOffice applications, and one of them - MSProject 2013, is behaving very unstable and strange.

Sometimes it starts just fine, and works fine, but from time to time it is bugging us with following error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {36D27C48-A1E8-11D3-BA55-00C04F72F325} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

This can happen at any time, does not matter if windows was rebooted a few seconds ago, or uptime is several hours and MSProject was opened and closed several times.

What can we do to solve, or at least diagnose root cause of such a behavior?

Comment: Is this application a multi-threaded app? Are you launching this COM interop asynchronously? Do you need more than one COM interop instance open at the same time?

Comment: Yes, the app is multithreaded, and we are using 1 instance of COM interop, and we are using OleMessageFilter to avoid "app is busy" exceptions.

Comment: I also think it is worth mentioning that in this particular case we are instantiating COM Interop in UI thread.

Answer (score -1):

this is a generic the best answer
Using DCOMCNFG.exe. Open it and go to: Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application.

Open the properties, select Identity tab and select the interactive user.

come from this link [Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062284/server-execution-failed-exception-from-hresult-0x80080005-co-e-server-exec-fa)

but the actual error caused a memory issue which leaded to the exception from hresult 0x80080005 error.
check if maybe open file and didn't close it after reading msProject check the behavior of the code.

- Also i recommend to change COM and read MsProject from XML to be faster and more clear than interop