# Exception "Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID" when creating new object

Tags: c#, iis, clsid

I have C# project which i'm publishing using IIS.
Tried to debug webPage and found that on code line

```
var SilApi = new SilApi();
```

webPage got stuck and it's keep loading something. After 10-20 min, it's stop loading and error appears.

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {AD0C0100-CE10-11DE-8F7A-005056C00008} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

Any ideas?

This is how SilApi looks like:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SilApi 
{
    [CoClass(typeof(SilApiClass))]
    [Guid("AD0C0001-CE10-11DE-8F7A-005056C00008")]
    public interface SilApi : ISilApi 
    {
    }
}
```

This is how ISilApi  looks like:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SilApi  
{
    [Guid("AD0C0001-CE10-11DE-8F7A-005056C00008")]
    [TypeLibType(4160)]
    public interface ISilApi  
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        ISilDocumentFactory SilDocumentFactory { get; }
        [DispId(2)]
        ISilPackageFactory SilPackageFactory { get; }
        [DispId(5)]
        ISilSpecificationFactory SilSpecificationFactory { get; }
       <....>
        [DispId(6)]
        IX509CertificateFactory X509CertificateFactory { get; }

        [DispId(33)]
        IMap GetNewMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Something went wrong with the COM server application. Possible hints can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062284/server-execution-failed-exception-from-hresult-0x80080005-co-e-server-exec-fa) or [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2005/06/24/when-cocreateinstance-returns-0x80080005-co_e_server_exec_failure/).

Comment: It's talking about problems with Excel and Word and "Component Services/Computers/DCOM Config/Microsoft Word97 - 2003 Document properties/General Tab" modifications. In my case, I am not working with Excel, so I am not sure what I should edit on Component Services/Computers/DCOM Config.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what this SilApi server is, but it seems to be a COM Server like Excel and Word.

Comment: SilApi is 3rd party dll which I added through "Component Services -> Computers -> MyComputer -> COM+ Applications"