# Excel Interop works in one solution in another same code produces an error (Parsing xlsx to DataTable)

Tags: c#

I have a code for parsing Excel to Datatable. It works in one solution, but in another one it produces an error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class
> factory for component with CLSID
> {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
> error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).'

pointing at:

```
NsExcel.Application xlApp = new NsExcel.Application();
```

I just have tested both and same error is coming in one of the solutions again and again. How this is possible? I have also checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39725040/7202022 and my settings are already as suggested in this answer. I have also tried to run Visual Studio as administrator without any success.

I know I can move to ClosedXML, but how come that it is working in one project and does not work in another?

Here is my full code:

```
    using NsExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    public static void ParseFromExcelFileToList(string FolderPath)
    {

        var FileToParse = "";

        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);
        foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.xlsx"))
        {
            // Rest of the code goes here 
            Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);

            FileToParse = file.FullName;
        }

        //Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is referenced
        NsExcel.Application xlApp = new NsExcel.Application();
        NsExcel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileToParse);
        NsExcel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[2];
        NsExcel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count - 5;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        //iterate over the rows and columns and print to the console as it appears in the file
        //excel is not zero based!!
        for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            // Parsing Excel column number 1
            string ProjectNumber = xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2;

            // Parsing Excel column number 2
            string SubProjectNumber = xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value2;

            // Parsing Excel column number 3
            string SubProjectName = xlRange.Cells[i, 3].Value2;

            // Parsing Excel column number 4
            string ProjectManager = xlRange.Cells[i, 4].Value2;

            foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1, 1))
                DeliverySubProjectList.Add(new SubProjectsList (ProjectNumber, SubProjectNumber, SubProjectName, "0", ProjectManager, 0));
        }

        //cleanup
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
        //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
        //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

        //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

        //close and release
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

        //quit and release
        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

    }
```

Comment: did you check you have the dependency installed?

Comment: I really wouldn't use Interop for anything if you can help it. It's not reliable. If you're reading from an excel file just use a library which reads the file directly instead of trying to invoke the whole Excel application in memory. There EppPlus, NPOI and a few others which can do the job

Comment: @ADyson so you mean to use something like ClosedXML?

Comment: Yes. But there are several options besides closedXML. Almost anything is preferable to Interop though. That's only for when you want to actually directly control excel on screen really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my third attempt to open my project in the middle of the night. I remembered having x64 Office installed. So I have tried to change settings and it worked.
Please don't close this question if you don't find this being a duplicate. I think somebody else maybe find this one useful.

Issue can be solved by changing properties:

In Visual Studio (I have Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019) go to **Project** - > **Properties** -> **Build** -> Uncheck "Prefer 32-bit" and Select correct "Platform target"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the error you faced. But why not try another solution? I was faced some issues with interop so I came up with this solution using OleDbDataAdapter.

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
var dataTable = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

Interop also depends on Microsoft Excel, where OleDbDataAdapter doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there any way to assign columns separately? I mean something like what I am doing `DeliverySubProjectList.Add(new SubProjectsList (ProjectNumber, SubProjectNumber, SubProjectName, "0", ProjectManager, 0));`

Comment: Yes you can do it. It is just like sql query.