# COM class factory for component CLSID{ID}failed due to the error: 80080005 Server execution failed (0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))

Tags: .net-core, com, interop

[image]

I have created a web application in dotnet core 6, I have given COM reference of FANUC SDK. Application is working in debug mode but after publish I am getting below error after publishing the website on server

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

I have applied below change and also publish in x86 but still getting the same error

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component/d801f311-cc39-4d83-8058-a209ef8f97cf

[Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062284/server-execution-failed-exception-from-hresult-0x80080005-co-e-server-exec-fa)

Comment: This is a pretty generic COM error. It's caused by the COM object you're using or the way it's setup or configured, etc. You should contact the vendor.