# How do I fix 'Server execution failed' error (code 80080005) while trying to open Excel from PowerPoint in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm working on a PowerPoint VBA script updating Excel-linked charts (for each chart, it opens the associated Excel file and updates the link). I've found a script and adjusted it a bit:

```
Sub UpdateLinks()

    'Declare PowerPoint Variables
    Dim PPTSlide As Slide
    Dim PPTShape As Shape

    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook

    'Create a new Excel Application, make it invisible, set the Excel Display alerts to False.
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visible = False
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Loop through each slide in the Presentation.
    For Each PPTSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides

        'Loop through Each Shape in the slide
        For Each PPTShape In PPTSlide.Shapes

            'If the Shape is a linked OLEObject.
            If PPTShape.Type = msoChart Then
                'LinkedOLEObject
                'Get the Source File of the shape.
                SourceFile = PPTShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName

               'This will open the file as read-only, and will not update the links in the Excel file.
                Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(SourceFile, False, True)

                    'Update the link
                    PPTShape.LinkFormat.Update

                'Close the workbook and release it from memory.
                xlWorkBook.Close
                Set xlWorkBook = Nothing

            End If

        Next PPTShape
    Next PPTSlide

    'Close the Excel App & release it from memory
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I've done the testing on my home computer with Office 365, it works fine. However, when I try to run the code on my office computer with Office 2016 (on which I actually need to run the script), upon reaching the line `Set xlapp = New Excel.Application` the error from the title ('Server Execution Failed') occurs.
I've checked the Excel Object Library in References, it's properly turned on. Apart from checking if Excel Object Library is referenced, I've tried another type of declaration:

```
Dim xlapp as Object
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

It would still throw the same error on the `Set` line.
There are no Excel instances running when the code is run. What is more, doing the reverse (creating a new PowerPoint.Application through a VBA script in Excel) works with no problem on the office desktop.

Do you have any idea what might cause such an error? How could I fix it?

Comment: Possibly some type of antivirus action?

Comment: ...or there's something wrong with your Excel install at work.  Other possible fixes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062284/server-execution-failed-exception-from-hresult-0x80080005-co-e-server-exec-fa

Comment: I haven't noticed any notifications popping up, but I guess it could prevent Excel from starting with no warning. Also, I was able to start a PowerPoint instance through a script (though the AV could be set to block just Excel).