# Importing MS Access reports to SSRS in Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services, ms-access-2013

In the past we have successfully imported reports from MS Access to Visual Studio (SSRS Project).
Recently I started getting this error.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)). (Microsoft Visual Studio)

Program Location:

at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Import.AccessImporter.EnsureDatabaseOpened()
at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Import.AccessImporter.GetReportList()
at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Import.AccessImportWizard.Execute(Object application, IntPtr hwndOwner, Object[]& contextParams, Object[]& customParams, wizardResult& retval)

> 

We tried the solution in the link provided (same steps but for MS Access)
[Component Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062284/server-execution-failed-exception-from-hresult-0x80080005-co-e-server-exec-fa)