# cant use scanner through iis WIA.CommonDialog 80070005 Access is denied

Tags: .net

Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {850D1D11-70F3-4BE5-9A11-77AA6B2BB201} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {850D1D11-70F3-4BE5-9A11-77AA6B2BB201} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Comment: Change the app pool identity to an actual user, first try the System user to see if that solves the issue, then switch to a user with the least privileges needed to create that COM component.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927392/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-creating-an-instance-of-the-com-component-fa